# How to access to de Markers from openlayers in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to access the markers from jquery, to create a new marker on the map, but it tells me is not defined markers.

node.js into onReady

```
var onReady = function () {
    window.client = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    client.on('connect', function (socket) {
        // usuario
        window.user = {
            id : client.socket.sessionid,
        }
        client.emit('infouser', user);
    });
    client.on('events', function(event){
        console.log(event)
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/icon.png',size,offset);
        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(event.long,event.lat);
        var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var lonlatEPSG = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlatEPSG, icon));
    });
}
$(document).ready(onReady)
```

openlayers.js into onReady

```
var onReady = function () {
    var mapa;
    OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    OpenLayers.ImgPath = "/openlayers/img/"
    mapa = new OpenLayers.Map('mapa',{
        controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        ],
        theme: null
    });
    // capas
    var osm  = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( " Open Street Map" );
    var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        " Google Hibrido",
        {type:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,sphericalMercator:true,numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
    // Marcadores
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Rute" );
    $.each(flota_mapa, function(i, data){
        var size   = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon   = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/icon.png',size,offset);
        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(data.long,data.lat);
        var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var EPSG   = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(EPSG, icon);
        marker.PlaneID = data.PlanetID;
        console.log(data.PlanetID);
        console.log(marker);
        markers.addMarker(marker);
    });
    console.log(markers);
    // centrar el mapa
    var lonlat  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-74.075833,4.598056);
    var proj_1  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var proj_2  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var centrar = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
    // Control de las capas
    mapa.addLayers([osm,ghyb,markers]);
    mapa.setCenter(centrar, 5);
    mapa.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
// Cuando el documento este listo
$(document).ready(onReady)
```

The error in DOM:

Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
var onReady = function () {
    var mapa;
    OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    OpenLayers.ImgPath = "/openlayers/img/"
    mapa = new OpenLayers.Map('mapa',{
        controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        ],
        theme: null
    });
    var osm  = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( " Open Street Map" );
    var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        " Google Hibrido",
        {type:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,sphericalMercator:true,numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Rute" );
    $.each(flota_mapa, function(i, data){
        var size   = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon   = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/icon.png',size,offset);
        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(data.long,data.lat);
        var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var EPSG   = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(EPSG, icon);
        marker.PlaneID = data.PlanetID;
        console.log(data.PlanetID);
        console.log(marker);
        markers.addMarker(marker);
    });
    window.client = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    client.on('events', function(event){
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/event/icon.png',size,offset);
        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(event.long,event.lat);
        var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var EPSG   = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(EPSG, icon);
        marker.PlaneID = data.PlanetID;
        console.log(data.PlanetID);
        console.log(marker);
        markers.addMarker(marker);
    var lonlat  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-74.075833,4.598056);
    var proj_1  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var proj_2  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var centrar = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
    mapa.addLayers([osm,ghyb,markers]);
    mapa.setCenter(centrar, 5);
    mapa.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
$(document).ready(onReady)
```